# No sounds when using browsers

Tags: audio, browser, windows-10

I updated my operating system to Windows 10 then I changed sounds to WASAPI. Now there is no sounds when using browsers (Chrome & Edge).

Answer (score -1):

I succeeded to solve the problem. I found out that after "playing" few times with the sound settings they seem to change but actually nothing happens. So I rebooted  my PC selected USB HEADSET ... as default device and everything started to work. Now it seems that this is a bug in Windows 10. Can someone else confirm this?